# Will pixel and resolution of an image affect the texture painting?

Tags: texturing, image, texture-painting, resolution

I am a beginner of blender. I would like to ask if the pixel or resolution of an image will affect the texture painting quality? Is it that using a higher pixel or resolution image will turn out a better quality of texture shown in blender than using a lower one?

Comment: You are correct. You must also take the UV unwrapping (search for some tutorials on the net) into account. The UVs dictate, how much texture (image) space each 3D face gets. If your UV islands are very small and don't use a lot of space on the image, they will cover very few pixels and the resolution will be poor. You want a large image with UVs, that use the space as much as possible. 2048x2048 or 4096x4096 are the norm for medium sized assets.

Comment: The resolution you need will depend on the kind of shots (image or animation) you'll make of your object, if you use low-res and there is no chance that you'll see that it's a low resolution because your camera won't go close enough, you can keep a low-resolution picture